# Converapi - Pdf Limitation and Load

Tags: convertapi

We are thinking to use ConverAPI component to handle the pdf conversion in our application.
But we are still unclear about the Limitation of Pdf generation and the Load handling.

1. How much Load will it support to do the pdf conversion? (e.g. in a sequence if we send 100 request at a time to do the pdf conversion will it work without any crash?)
2. What is the limitation of handling the pdf conversion? (e.g. if i send a document size around 800MB -1024MB will it be able to handle it for doing the Pdf conversion?)

Answer (score 1):

1. 100 simultaneous file uploads is inefficient. The best is to use ~4 (and it also highly depends on the situation). If you are really planning to convert 100x1Gb files simultaneously, please consult with the support.
2. The hard limit is 1Gb for files that are processed. Rest depends on file complexity and conversion.

The best would be to register and try it for free with your files.